# JSON-serialization of complex Pandas types to store them into DynamoDB

Tags: python, json, pandas, amazon-dynamodb

We're trying to store data parsed from a PDF into a DynamoDB table.
Some of the "entities" that we extract from the text have a corresponding type builtin into DynamoDB, e.g. `float`, `boolean`, `string`...

However, there are some entities which can not be represented in terms of builtin types.
For example, we're extracting some time offsets defined in terms of business days, which we decided to represent as `pandas.tseries.offsets`

```py
from pandas.tseries import offsets

offsets.BusinessDay(2)

>>> <2 * BusinessDays>
```

This cannot be saved directly into DynamoDB, so we thought of serializing it into JSON beforehand

```json
{
   "type": "offsets.BusinessDay",
   "value": 2
}
```

and to write some conversion functions to get the original object back with the right type whenever we need to use it to do some computations.

The problem is that this is hard to generalize to different complex types, as the parameter(s) used to define the object (in this case "2", the number of business days) change.
We would like to find a generalized way to serialize a complex type to a JSON representation so that something like this

```py
var = complexType(param1=2, param2='a')
```

would be automatically translated into something like this

```json
varJSON = {
   "type": "complexType",
   "param1": 2,
   "param2": 'a'
}
```

which can then hopefully be converted back to the original type by doing something like (in pseudo-code, I don't know whether it makes sense!)

```py
var = varJSON["type"](**params)
```

Is this stupid? :) Any way to do this?

Comment: 'as the parameter(s) change' - use a function argument? Or do you have loads of custom types? Is there any `to_json` methods on the offset object itself like the one on dataframes?

Comment: No, unfortunately. But that makes sense as it is not a dataframe

Comment: Serialise the object to a string and see if the output contains everything you need to create it back up again when deserialising